# Is it possible to formulate the development cost?

Tags: formula

Is there any formula showing the development cost of an application?

Basically not to reach a very specific number but at least stressing what parts are effecting the overall cost in what magnitude?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about business administration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Estimated Cost = M x L

M = Total adjusted labor man-hours
L = Labor rate per man-hour
```

From http://ecmweb.com/mag/electric_calculating_true_labor/ which is not software industry specific but most of the ideas should apply. Probably.

Comment: So, I think the chosen technology or programming language is also affecting the argument 'M' Let's to do the same thing you may need to write mor lines of code in one language where much less might be enough in the other.

Comment: Not really. It depends on the 'man' - if the 'man' is only proficient with a hammer then he'll take longer to do the same task with a drill. If you catch my drift.

Answer (score 0):

What I do to estimate the cost of an app is to break down into "small" sub-tasks and estimate the amount of work for each one. Then add some needed work for specifications, design, integration, user testing, and project management.

Then, assign these tasks to the different kinds of people in the team (developers, managers, architects, etc.) and sum the products of labor rate x man-hours in each category.

So, it is not easy at all...